# I want to find automatically enemies and put a target on the closest of them. Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, target, auto, closest

I would like to put a target on the location of : closest.

p.s. I'm new at this.

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject FindClosestEnemy()
    {
        GameObject[] gos;
        gos = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");
        GameObject closest = null;
        float distance = Mathf.Infinity;
        Vector3 position = transform.position;
        foreach (GameObject go in gos)
        {
            Vector3 diff = go.transform.position - position;
            float curDistance = diff.sqrMagnitude;
            if (curDistance < distance)
            {
                closest = go;
                distance = curDistance;
            }
        }    //can i put for exemple this specific gameobjet (target)
             //on the closest enemyobject
             //target.transform.position = closest.transform.position;
        return closest;
     }
}
```

Making a turret follow a target i figured, but automatically find a closest target i just don't understand yet

Comment: What's the issue you are having?

Comment: well, i would like to place a game object on the location of the variable closest.

Comment: or to make the closest variable a target that's can be followed by my AI turret

Comment: But you said "can I do this" in your comments and showed some code, what's the issue you are having with what you've tried?

Comment: the target stays on the player instead of going on the nearest enemy.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use [Linq `OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby) and [`First`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first) to get the closest object

```
using System.Linq;
...

public GameObject FindClosestEnemy()
{
    GameObject[] enemies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");

    // If no enemies found at all directly return nothing
    // This happens if there simply is no object tagged "Enemy" in the scene
    if(enemies.Length == 0)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("No enemies found!", this);
        return null;
    }

    GameObject closest;

    // If there is only exactly one anyway skip the rest and return it directly
    if(enemies.Length == 1)
    {
        closest = enemies[0];
        target.transform.position = closest.transform.position;
        return closest;
    }


    // Otherwise: Take the enemies
    closest = enemies
    // Order them by distance (ascending) => smallest distance is first element
        .OrderBy(go => (position - go.transform.position).sqrMagnitude)
    // Get the first element
        .First();

    target.transform.position = closest.transform.position;

    return closest;
 }
```

Comment: i'll trie that today :) lets see what happens next.

Comment: I downvoted because you recommended use of `Vector3.Distance`, which is inefficient and not recommended (for production use, anyway). I've removed the downvote as you edited your answer to `sqrMagnitude` (which is the efficient method).

Comment: @vasmos `Vector3.Distance` equals basically using `(a-b).magnitude` where the magnitude again is basically `Mathf.Sqrt(Vector3.Dot(v, v))`. By using the [`sqrMagnitude`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-sqrMagnitude.html) property instead you skip this calculation. Since you are not interested in the exact value but only want to compare them you get the same results by using the square since if `|x| < |y|` then automatically also `x² < y²` .. which is cheaper to compare => 1,0,0 and 0,1,0 will also have the same sqrMagnitude

Comment: @AStopher [`FindGameObjectsWithTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) returns an `GameObject[]` which is not a `List<GameObject>` therefore also `Count` is wrong and needs to be `Length`. Using `var` is totally fine and even recommended if the return type is known and even if not using `var` is not `bad practice` ..  just because some do prefer or recommend to not use it too much I wouldn't generalize it to a common convention. Anyway every serious IDE will tell you what type the field/variable has

Comment: @derHugo True, I was thinking of something else (sorry). However I still disagree with usage of `var` as it hurts readability... and I've never read anything that would imply that using `var` would be OK for readability's sake when the type is known. In the editor you could get away with it (because it will tell you what it's supposed to be), but on Stack Overflow I'd argue readability is key and so `var` isn't a good idea here. There's probably a good Q&A somewhere that discusses this actually...

Comment: @AStopher there are a lot discussion about that but no real convention. Due to the type inference in c# I prefer `var` in most cases since it allows you to quickly exchange return types without having to touch everything. In this case it is known that `FindObjectsWithTag` just like every Unity built-in method that returns multiple results returns an array .. they never return lists. It is opinions in this case (there are others where I would agree with you)

Comment: Really not sure why you've just reverted my edit that improves readability... I've flagged for a moderator as this has become an edit war. On Stack Overflow it is critical that the readability of a question or answer is good so it can be understood, changing `var` to the correct variable improves readability. Microsoft docs discourage use of `var`: "However, the use of var does have at least the potential to make your code more difficult to understand for other developers." Can hardly argue with the C# docs... All I'm saying is: please do not teach others to use `var` as it is just being lazy.

Answer (score 0):

I came with this solution from a tutorial on youtube.
at first, i didn't understand the list. I thought that List GameObject was a object and not a type. etc. etc.
the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6rDlfYC4HxM
He had a method that i actually didn't have "(FindClosest)".
That's why i came here because i didn't understand this tutorial and the unity tutorial that i showed you before.
    `public class TARGETER_SCAN : MonoBehaviour
    {
    public string detected_TAG1;
    public string detected_TAG2;
        public List<GameObject> Enemies_list = new List<GameObject>();
        public List<GameObject> TARGETER_LIST = new List<GameObject>();
    }
    void Start()
    {
    foreach (GameObject Enemies in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(detected_TAG1))
                {
                    Enemies_list.Add(Enemies);
                }

    foreach (GameObject TARGETER in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(detected_TAG2))
                {
                    TARGETER_LIST.Add(TARGETER);
                }
    }
    void Update()
    { 
    foreach (var TARGETER in TARGETER_LIST)
    {
                    var nearest = float.MaxValue;
                    GameObject NearestEnemie = null;
    foreach (var Enemies in Enemies_list)
        {

    if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, enemies.transform.position) < nearest)
        {
         nearest = (Vector3.Distance(transform.position,Enemies.transform.position));
         NearestEnemie = Enemies;
         target.transform.position = NearestEnemie.transform.position;
        }
    }
    }`

What are your thoughts. I don't know if i copied it properly here. I made it work this morning on my project. And it's functional.

Comment: But i'll trie your solution too :)